# Format JSON for 3 input fields

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

I need to generate json from the serverside, which I know how to do.  However, I do not know how to format this json data so it can easily be used in jQuery?

here is the script I have at the moment.  What is the best way to format json data so I can fill in 3 input fields?

```
$('input#btnGet').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'generate_json.aspx',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { intPageID:1 },
        success: function(results) { 
            $('input#id').val('id goes here');
            $('input#heading').val('heading goes here');
            $('input#content').val('content goes here');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add `dataType: 'json'` to your options, then jQuery directly decodes the JSON into a JavaScript object:

> "json": Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object. In jQuery 1.4 the JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown. (See json.org for more information on proper JSON formatting.)

Assuming the JSON you receive/generate is

```
'{"id": 6, "heading": "heading", "content": "content"}'
```

your code would look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'generate_json.aspx',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { intPageID:1 },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(results) { 
        $('#id').val(results.id);
        $('#heading').val(results.heading);
        $('#content').val(results.content);
    }
});
```

If your JSON string represents an array instead, then of course `results` would be a JavaScript array and you have to loop over it.

---

Btw. as IDs are unique, there is not need to prepend the tag name in the selector.

Comment: And with ID's it is actually bad to add tag name as there are explicit built in functions in the DOM for fetching elements by ID alone that are the fastest way and jQuery can use them with a pure ID selector :)

Answer (score 1):

Just specify dataType as "json" and you're set!

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'generate_json.aspx',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { intPageID:1 },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result){$("#heading").val(result.heading)}
    });
```

Comment: This does not answer his question on how to format the JSON string from the server in the first place, only how to parse it on the client ;)

Comment: @David Mårtensson: well, there's only one way to format JSON... the way the JSON standard dictates! :) (`json_encode` PHP function does the job pretty well in this sense).

Answer (score 1):

If you server returns this:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "heading": "yadayada"
  "content": "foobar"
}
```

You can use it like:

```
success: function(results) { 
   $('input#id').val(results.id);
   $('input#heading').val(results.heading);
   $('input#content').val(results.content);
}
```